# microsoft word: creating subdocument 'Normal' style issues

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, styles

I am creating subdocuments from a large master document.  I'm using the feature to break up our specification and make it easier for my team to collaborate.  It's on the order of 500 subdocuments.

I can easily create all of the subdocuments I need automatically.  However, the style features are not carrying over.  Although the formatting hasn't changed in the master document, the subdocument is formatted differently.  It doesn't appear to be related to the styles.  I think it has to do with the template.  For example, the styled fonts and tables match the master document.  However the Normal fonts do not match the master document.  Also, the Normal paragraph settings do not match the master document.  For example, I have the master document set to single spacing.  However, every subdocument is created with double spacing as default.  I also have the master document set to Arial size 10 for Normal font.  The subdocument is created with a Calibri size 11 font for the Normal setting.
Is there a way I can choose the template that a subdocument is created from?
Is there a way to make the Normal styling carry over from the master document to the subdocuments?